# Git/Gitlab Push RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411

Tags: git, nginx, push, gitlab

i got a problem with Git, i get an rpc error when pushing a large Commit over http
(RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411)

Since ssh is really slow (about 250 - 300 kb/s) and the commit is about 7 gb i REALLY want to use http for this.

I am google'ing since yesterday but can't find an answer.

As is stated in the title i'm using gitlab. I already changed the pustBuffer size locally, set the client_max_body_size in nginx and updated the commit size in the gitlab.yml and changed the pack sizes, but nothing helped.

Do you have an idea what i could try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are significant tradeoffs that you should be aware of before adding large files to a Git repository, with the general advice being avoid it if possible. Because of this, many hosts enforce repository size limits (for example, GitHub [limits repositories to 1GB](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/)). That limit is for the *entire repository*; there are often limits on file size as well. Why is your commit so large?

Comment: Because there is no other way, this repo is for an Unreal Engine Project and the assets are kinda huge. I already had the idea to store them outside of git but that didn't worked that good. And yes i know that this will bloat up the entire repo ;)

Comment: Have you looked at [`git-annex`](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), [`git-fat`](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat), or [GitHub's LFS extension](https://git-lfs.github.com/)? Storing 7GB of (presumably) binary data directly in Git really isn't a great idea.

Comment: It isn't but there aren't any good other choices, storing assets in (for example) dropbox and copy them over all the time isn't great either. I'll have a look at annex, but since it isn't integrated in gitlab (ce) and i don't want to lose the advantages of it, it doesn't seem to be a good alternative (and i still have to upload the data, which means the problem isn't solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was caused by the "nativ" Nginx version of Debian 7. In there Repo's it has version 1.2.1 and in this Version it doesn't support chunked files. Updating Nginx over DotDep to version 1.6 solved the Problem.